# Windows Azure Basic Authentication

Tags: authentication, azure, basic-authentication

I need to set up a testing website on Windows Azure, and typically to prevent random people from looking at it I would have set up basic authentication with some sort of trivial password to filter people. Windows Azure, seemingly, does not have this option.

What are the alternatives? So far I am considering implementing another level of forms authentication but this is a lot of work and would need to be stripped out in the production version of the site.

The documentation on implementing Basic-Authentication in the web.config is also shockingly sparse.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you should be able to use the IIS7 demo BasicAuthenticationModule to achieve what you want - see full code and instructions in
http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/170/developing-a-module-using-net/

Comment: ok, one caveat; you don't have access to appcmd.exe in azure, so there is no way to disable anonymous authentication. still stuck here.

Comment: I think you have access to appcmd - lots of bing/google hits like http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-CA/windowsazuredevelopment/thread/e51ad615-1dd1-48c6-8f82-365b6a0c8137

Comment: more concise version of the fix here (that applies to what i was stuck on) http://richardprodger.wordpress.com/2011/03/22/azure-iis7-configuration-with-appcmd/

Comment: also, how/where to add the .cmd http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg456327.aspx